# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when add Moment to Bootstrap Date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

To be straightforward, here's the code of my picker:

```js
import {moment} from 'moment';

const datePicker = () => {
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    locale: 'PT-BR',
    icons: {
      up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
      down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
    },
    stepping: 15,
    disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 18 }), moment({ h: 24 })]]
  });
};

export {datePicker};
```

The line `disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 18 }), moment({ h: 24 })]]` is coming direct from [the documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals).

But adding it causes `dtPicker.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

you are importing moment the wrong way

```
import moment from "moment"; // correct way
```

this answer is after 10 months but may help others